# MongoDB Defaulting to Strict Mode

Tags: mongodb

We have a nodejs + mongodb application that has been running in production for several years, and in development on multiple machines. On just one developer's machine, I'm seeing the error

```
MongoError: collection already exists
```

Researching this error indicates that this will occur when trying to create an existing collection only if the collection is in strict mode. We don't invoke mongo's strict mode anywhere in our application, and we can only reproduce this error on one machine.

Code which causes this error is as follows:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
mongo.MongoClient.connect(config.mongoConnectionString, {w:1}, function(err, db) {
  db.createCollection('accounts', function(err, collection) {
    // "err" here is the error message.
  });
});
```

Is there a way to override mongo's default `strict: false` value? Is there a global configuration option that causes strict mode to be turned on? I would rather not modify the code to specify `strict: false` for every collection just to enable a single developer. The developer is running mongo v3.2

Comment: edited above. As I mentioned this code has been running in staging and production environments for two years, and many developers are able to run this code. Only a single machine seems to be having this problem. If we manually bypass errors for this collection we see the same error for all other collections on this machine, which leads me to believe that there is a config value for the installed version of mongo itself, rather than a problem with our code.

Comment: Did that developer install mongoose as well by any chance ?

Comment: @JohnnyHK An old version. 1.2.14

Comment: @Jaco not sure, let me double check. Would mongoose interfere?

Comment: @aaaarrgh Wow, that's ancient. Are all your devs using that version?

Comment: Unlike the Node.JS Mongo driver, new versions of Mongoose enforces `strict:true` by default, so indeed wondering if a Mongoose installation is interfering with the mongodb core libraries.

Comment: @jaco good thought, but i just checked and there are no mongeese either in the project directory or installed globally ( `npm ls mongoose` or `npm --global ls mongoose`

Comment: @JohnnyHK yeah its what's specified in the package.json. We're doing a rewrite for a v2.0 of our api, but the old api will continue to be supported so we still need devs and testers to be able to work with the old dependencies for the time being

Answer (score 2):

You can disable 'strict' mode by using this

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
mongo.MongoClient.connect(config.mongoConnectionString, {w:1}, function(err, db) {
  db.createCollection('accounts', {strict:false}, function(err, collection) {
    // "err" here is the error message.
  });
});
```

you can read more about this from [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collection)

Comment: I've already discovered this; I'm loath to change stable code that runs in production in order to fix an issue that is only occurring on one dev's machine. This question is about finding the configuration that is causing the errant behavior on the one machine, rather than disrupting all other working configurations